# How can i add additional parameter to cordova.exec success function

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and js, and phonegap provides a function

`cordova.exec(success,fail,'service','action',args);`

The success function only has one argument that is post back from the background.

I wonder if i can add additional arguments to this function to pass data created from js.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 cordova.exec(function(argOfSuccessFunction){
           success(argOfSuccessFunction,yourArgs)
  },fail,'service','action',args);
```

Call success as callback here.

Comment: Glad to know that :) Welcome,pleasure is mine.